# Kafka message loss and Acks=all

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I understand if Acks=all and min ISR is set to >= 2 reduces the chance of message loss as more than one broker has the message in memory. What happens when there is a simultaneous failure of connectivity between producer and brokers 
1 before the message is acked but request sent to leader for write. 
2 message were written but failed during ack

Is there any chance of message loss ?

Comment: 'failure of connectivity between client and brokers'. Did you mean `producer` when you say 'client' ?

Comment: Edited to reflect  producer instead of client

Comment: `A typical scenario would be to create a topic with a replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and produce with acks of "all". This will ensure that the producer raises an exception if a majority of replicas do not receive a write`

Comment: @Deadpool I have mentioned those assumptions in the question already. I am curious about connectivity loss after. Write request is sent and or finished but producer has not processed the response. Is it only loss of ack ?

Comment: Actually producer stores these messages into buffer and buffer is responsible of sending these messages as batch to kafka cluster, and to your point `is it only loss of ack` yes but that might be very rare @Balan

Comment: It would have helped if there were any sort of message correlation Id in acknowledgement to guard against such failures however rare those may be. I don’t see a provision for getting any passthrough data back in ack RecordMetadata.

Comment: You might want to try enabling idempotent settings as well

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah Idempotent helps, but it does not guard against ack loss completely. Rare but happens

Answer (score 2):

When producer send data to brokers, actually it send only to only one - the *leader*. *Leader* broker should confirm that message has been received. If you configure broker as described, the *leader* will await acknowledgments from replicas. If something goes wrong, the *leader* don't send its own confirmation. When producer doesn't receive acknowledgment from the *leader*, it will understand that message has NOT been delivered. 
For simplicity, I dropped out that there are some retires before any failure message.

Assuming that,

1. Since producer doesn't receive ack, it will re-send original message. If connection has been restored then broker could see that this message has been received already. Then broker send ack to producer.
2. If message was written to the *leader* but replicas was failed to ack, then *leader* will treat such message as not saved and remove from its storage.